# How Do I Use Jquery UI-Button-MVC

Tags: jquery-ui

I am looking to use Jquery UI button in my MVC Application.  Could anybody tell me, what files I need to download from here [Jquery Download](http://jqueryui.com/download). and Where to place them and the references?

I know there is View Source at this Location [Source for Button](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/).

I don't know, I need to use css files and images . But don't know, where to place them, Could anyone point me step by step in right direction please.

I am taking this approach as I have some compatiblity issues with browsers when I use custom buttons.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For jquery u can try to use it this way in your head tag :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("jquery", "1");
        google.load("jqueryui", "1");
    </script>
```

and for the css just look which one u need here http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

and add it like this :

`@import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css";`

for example for the smoothness theme